# Is it possible to change mysql DB encoding charset from within a laravel migration?

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm attempting to change the encoding of a mysql DB in Laravel-5, I've tried with a migration, following this example: https://slashdot.io/blog/adding-emoji-support-to-your-blog-948181198 - However, nothing ever updates and the charset / encoding stays as it was.

Is it possible to do this with a migration? Or will I have to write a separate script?

**migration** (for completeness)

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    DB::raw('ALTER TABLE homestead.survey_responses CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci');
    DB::raw('REPAIR TABLE homestead.survey_responses');
    DB::raw('OPTIMIZE TABLE homestead.survey_responses');
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    DB::raw('ALTER TABLE homestead.survey_responses CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci');
    DB::raw('REPAIR TABLE homestead.survey_responses');
    DB::raw('OPTIMIZE TABLE homestead.survey_responses');
}
```

The above migration runs, without errors, but unfortunately does nothing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not possible using **Schema/Blueprint** classes that are usually used in migration classes. But you can still run any SQL you need using **DB** facade - in your case:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ChangeCharsetAndCollation Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        DB::statement('ALTER DATABASE database CHARACTER SET new_charset COLLATE new_collation');
    }

    public function down()
    {
        DB::statement('ALTER DATABASE database CHARACTER SET old_charset COLLATE old_collation');
    }
}
```

Just replace **database**, **old_charset**, **old_collation**, **new_charset**, **new_collation** with desired values and make sure your user has permissions to run such query.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) Is it normal to see this: [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered quer
  ies are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code
  is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the
  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute. (SQL: ALTER DATABASE homestead CHARACTER
  SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci) ?

Comment: Is there some other process that is using the database while you execute that migration?

Comment: That's what I though initially, but after checking, no :(

Comment: It might be related to previous queries run by PDO. Try to do DB::reconnect() before running DB::statement()

Comment: Cheers for that. I've decided to make up a bash script for it. Running this like I was, literally broke everything. And I don't like that :D Thanks though!

Comment: @LokiSinclair Hey Loki. I was wondering how you finally changed the charset and collation and if you ran into any problems while doing so. Did you run a bash script or migrate it with the migrate statement? Thanks!

Comment: You can also change that of a specific column using `DB::statement('ALTER TABLE your_db_name.table_name MODIFY COLUMN column_name text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL')`

Answer (score 11):

Big necro here.

Laravel 7 comes out of the box with functionality to change the charset and collation on a table. I needed this for Cashier/stripe.

[The documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#creating-tables) shows you how to do it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#creating-tables)

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    ....
    $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
    $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_bin';
});
```

**Edit**

Alternatively, and a better solution for me was to change the collation on a single column.

```
$table->string('name')->collation('utf8mb4_bin');
```

Comment: Cor! Way to dust this oldie off!

Answer (score 1):

If like me, you were trying to use `DB::statement('ALTER DATABASE database CHARACTER SET [...]')` but were left scratching your head over the confusing `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active` error...

The simple solution is to use DB::unprepared():

`DB::unprepared('ALTER DATABASE database CHARACTER SET [...]')` instead.

Credit to this gist: https://gist.github.com/NBZ4live/04d5981eaf0244b57d0296b381e04195

Comment: Way to raise the dead! :)

Comment: I ran into the same problem, ended up here, thought i'd share some wisdom! :)