# Are Chinese characters supported in migration tables?

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration, laravel-5

Are values consisting of Chinese characters and characters of other languages'  supported in migration tables for a Laravel app?

Comment: Maybe try setting the character encoding by `DB::raw` statements?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31540825/is-it-possible-to-change-mysql-db-encoding-charset-from-within-a-laravel-migrati

Comment: Can you put that in an answer so I can have the answer solved?

Comment: um..why do you want to do it. Ever most database is not support it now.

Comment: @WeiYuan I'm creating a dictionary-like app. haakym's answer of the `DB::raw` is probably the best solution. The rows will be the terms, columns will be the same term but of different languages. So when somebody searches a term, different languages of the same term will appear and be filtered when a different language option has been chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it's not supported, but for anything that's not supported you can try via `DB:raw`. For your case you can try setting the character encoding by `DB::raw`.

Check this question for examples: [Is it possible to change mysql DB encoding charset from within a laravel migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31540825/is-it-possible-to-change-mysql-db-encoding-charset-from-within-a-laravel-migrati)